# How to prevent Terraform from deleting a resource when index [0] is out of range for count

Tags: terraform, cloudflare

I have previously created A type cloudflare record and would like to keep it while adding another one. So I defined a flag to just skip it.

```
resource "cloudflare_record" "cloudflare-a-record" {
  count   = var.flag != false ? 1 : 0
  zone_id = var.zone_id
  name    = var.sub_domain
  type    = "A"
  value   = aws_eip.my_eip.public_ip
  ttl     = 1
  proxied = false
}

resource "cloudflare_record" "vault-cloudflare-cname-record" {
  count   = var.flag == false ? 1 : 0
  zone_id = var.zone_id
  name    = cloudflare_record.cloudflare-a-record.hostname
  type    = "CNAME"
  value   = aws_eip.my_eip.public_dns
  ttl     = 1
  proxied = false
}
```

But Terraform deleted this resource with the following message:

> cloudflare_record.vault-cloudflare-a-record[0] will be destroyed
> (because index [0] is out of range for count)

Is there another way to ignore this resource? Or is the code wrong?

Comment: Has the flag variable kept its value across applies?

Comment: "while adding another one" what does it mean? Your code does not demonstrate any extra one. Please provide full code demonstrating the issue which can be copied and pasted to reproduce your errors.

Comment: @MarkoE yes, flag variable is true or false as I pass it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you cannot use the same flag for two different resources as the variable value will remain the same for both A and CNAME resources. The way I see it there are two possible options with the current code since you are using different conditionals (in A you use `==` and in CNAME you use `!=`):

```
var.flag == false ? 1 : 0 # A record
var.flag != false ? 1 : 0 # CNAME record
```

This means if the `flag = false` the A record will be created (as the count will be `1`) and the CNAME record will not be created (as the count will be `0`). Now, if the `flag`'s value changes to `true`, then the A record will be deleted (as `true == false` will return `false`) and the CNAME record will be created (as `true != false` will be `true`). This means that the same `flag` should not be used for two different resources. You could use the same conditional for both resources, which means that both would be created/deleted together (not sure if that is what you want). A better way would be to define two variables, one for A and one for CNAME record:

```
variable "create_a_record" {
  type = bool
}

variable "create_cname_record" {
  type = bool
}
```

Then, in your code you would change the lines that use the `count` meta-argument to:

```
resource "cloudflare_record" "cloudflare-a-record" {
  count   = var.create_a_record ? 1 : 0
  zone_id = var.zone_id
  name    = var.sub_domain
  type    = "A"
  value   = aws_eip.my_eip.public_ip
  ttl     = 1
  proxied = false
}

resource "cloudflare_record" "vault-cloudflare-cname-record" {
  count   = var.create_cname_record ? 1 : 0
  zone_id = var.zone_id
  name    = cloudflare_record.cloudflare-a-record.hostname
  type    = "CNAME"
  value   = aws_eip.my_eip.public_dns
  ttl     = 1
  proxied = false
}
```

This way you can control if you want to have both created or only one. Also note the following:

```
count = var.create_a_record ? 1 : 0
count = var.create_cname_record ? 1 : 0
```

When variables are of type `bool` (`true` or `false`), when using them in conditionals, you do not have to check their equality against another boolean, as the left-most value will anyway be either `true` or `false`. So for example, if you set `create_a_record = true`, that would make the above expression:

```
count = true ? 1 : 0
```

and that would evaluate to `count = 1`. You could also set default values for variables, e.g., if you want to make sure the A record is always there, you can just do this:

```
variable "create_a_record" {
  type    = bool
  default = true
}
```

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/conditionals

Comment: Perfect, I'll use two flags, thank you so much!! And thank you for a code improvement suggestion!!!!

Comment: Always happy to help!